# How to remove duplicate set elements in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an entity of places called `Place` which has a relationship (`Set<Activity>`) and I am passing the places (fetch request) to the `PlacesView` and each place has a list of Activities. What I try to accomplish is, that instead of showing all activities related to a place directly, I want to pre-group them in date elements in a `ActivityDatesView`. Now I want to select the date and see all activities related to that place and date. Date is an attribute of the `Activity` entity.

How can I modify my code, to not display activities, that have the same `activity.date` (without time), where `activity.date` is Date() value coming from a CoreData entity and `Activity` is a `NSManagedObject Subclass`.

```
 List(Array(place.activities as Set), id: \.self) { activity in
     Text(dateFormatter.string(from: activity.date))
 }
```

For Views, I had:

```
struct PlacesView {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Place.name, ascending: true)]) var places: FetchedResults<Foo>
    var body: some View {
        //...
    }
}
struct ActivityDatesView {
    @ObservedObject var place: Place
    var body: some View {
        List(Array(place.activities as Set), id: \.self) { activity in
            Text(dateFormatter.string(from: activity.date)) // This displays duplicate entries
        }
    }
}
struct ActivityView {
    @ObservedObject var place: Place
    var selectedDate: Date
    var body: some View {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I just want a list of grouped dates without duplicates. I want to pass that that to a new `ActivityView` that displays all activities related to that selected date ungrouped.

Comment: sounds interesting - how can I transfer the NSManagedObject subclass to a dictionary?

Comment: The issue is, you can't iterate through a dictionary. I tried `List(Dictionary(grouping: palce.activites, by: { Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: $0.date) }))`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have an entity of places classed `Place` which has a relationship (`Set<Activity>') and I am passing the places (fetch request) to the `PlacesView` and each place has a list of Activities. What I try to accomplish is, that instead of showing all activities related to place directly, I want to pre-group them in date elements. Now I want to select the date and see all activities related to that place and date. Date is an attribute of the `Activity` entity.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question and added more value and the gathered information.

Answer (score 1):

Because to get the features of Set() your struct must be Hashable and Equatable if you customize this protocols and override the default provided functions you get the desired functionality with much less code. The best is all your dates save their time and you dont lose any information.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let activities = [Activity(date: Date()), Activity(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(3600)), Activity(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(24*3600))]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(Array(Set(activities))) { activity in
                    //prints 2 dates
                    Text(activity.date.description)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Activity: Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name = "Activity"
    var date: Date
    
    //Add this function to your struct
    static func == (lhs: Activity, rhs: Activity) -> Bool {
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: lhs.date) == Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: rhs.date)
    }
    
    //Add this function also to your struct
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date))
    }
}
```

Comment: I proposed an edit of your answer. If I'm right, please approve and thank you for the great hint with the locals. Anyhow... I my result shows duplicates after that change, but the time is equal for all now.

Comment: I completely changed my answer to easy readable and less code. This should be exactly what your looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your update. As I wrote, my activities are coming from a fetched request `place` that is passed to the View as an `@ObservedObject var place: Place` and I access is through `places.activity`. I think a NSManagedObject Subclass already conforms to these protocols - What do I need to do, to apply to that struct?

Comment: You need to override the == function and hash function to what i showed you in the example above

Comment: When I add the functions to my NSManagedObject class, it tells me `Overriding declarations in extensions is not supported`.

Comment: If you get this error move the function in the block where you first time defined your class and not where you extended it with the "extension" keyword

Comment: This error appears here: `@objc(Activity) public class Activity: NSManagedObject { func hash(...)`